# Microsoft Excel for calculating overtime based off daily AND weekly values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I’m trying to create an expense/income spreadsheet but my hours vary from week to week, therefore as part of the income section I have a place to enter my daily hours, call it the “Hours cell”. The problem I’m having is in calculating overtime hours.

Our pay is calculated as in any day over 8 pays OT for the 9th hour and on, AND any week over 40 regular hours, pays OT from then on. So I would need two arguments for a weekly total. It gets a little more difficult because Sundays pay Double Time as long as we’ve hit 60 TOTAL hours throughout the week.

A simple =MIN(8,”Hours cell”) and then another argument subtracting that value from the “Hours cell” yields the overtime hours worked in a day. However as the week progresses I don’t know how to add another argument to the Regular hours to calculate OT off the weekly 40.

I hope this makes sense, I didn’t want to ramble on and on. If anyone needs any clarification let me know. Thank you.

Clip of formula and results in right column, you can see the regular time exceeds 40 hours.
[image: Clip of formula and results in right column, you can see the regular time exceeds 40 hours]

Clip of formula for Overtime calculation, added more hours to total in this clip to show Doubletime functionality.
[image: Clip of formula for Overtime calculation, added more hours to total in this clip to show Doubletime functionality]

This image is in response to gns100 as I understood his suggestion.
[image: This image is in response to gns100 as I understood his suggestion]

Comment: Show us the spreadsheet with example data and explain what changes when "the week progresses".

Comment: Can't you just do the same thing on your weekly hours total to calculate OT based on the 40 hours, then (separate cell?) do a `MAX` between your daily total and that week calculation?

Comment: gns100, If i understand you correctly, i could do that if my OT was based solely on the 40 hours per week requirement. Im not sure how i would still calculate the 8 hours per day requirement too. Any time after 8 in a single day also needs to be classified as overtime.